# share image with Tumblr and Flickr in android

Tags: android, tumblr, image-uploading, android-image, flickr

I have searched a lot regarding tumblr and flickr to post an image using android app. Unfortunately I can not get more details regarding it.

So can anyone give me some examples or links or tutorial to upload a photo from android application? any sample example will also be fine for understanding purpose.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.